# Work with IT and Software Engineering in Germany and in New Zealand

Tags: working-visas, germany, new-zealand

I am leaving Brazil now, I have two job offers: one for New Zealand and one for Germany.

In New Zealand I will be working in Auckland and in Germany in Frankfurt.

I going to work as a programmer with languages such as Java, C#

Both companies have similar salaries.

So the questions is: What are the Fundamental differences between those two Countries for a Brazilian worker working as a programmer?

Please note I am not asking which one is better, or asking for opinions, but I really want to know what are the main differences in the day-to-day life and day-to-day work.

Note: I have not been to any of those countries.

Comment: Language? Culture? Sheep per capita? Weather? Hemisphere? Distance from Brazil?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. Both being considered "first world" Western countries, New Zealand and Germany have a lot of similarities with regard to employment as a software engineer. But a list of differences would still fill a book.

Comment: even two companies from each of those countries would be different...